# How To Promote Google TV Only Application

Tags: google-tv

I would like to know after I built an application for Google TV, how can I get the app listed under http://www.google.com/tv/apps.html, or does Google do anything to help promoting Google TV Only Apps? Since it takes a separate effort to design TV friendly UI and Navigation system,  what can we do to make it more visible to Google TV users? Right now the Play Store is very messy and unorganized in a way or it might only because the country I am located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should contact the Google TV developer advocates. In particular, [Les Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738710/les-vogel-google-tv-devrel), or [Krispy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195515/krispy). In the past they have looked at apps and provided feedback. They have also helped to get interesting apps into the featured section of the Play Store on Google TV.

You might also consider joining the [Sony Developer Network](http://www.developer.sony.com/), which allows you to upload your app and have them test it on their Google TV devices. They provide a test report which will help to make your app better for the TV experience. If they like your app, they can also add it to their own featured app section of the Play Store on their Google TV devices.

There is a [Google TV community on G+](https://plus.google.com/communities/103154508693468858359/stream/3259fe34-4cda-43e6-aae7-e9ee724ec24b) where you can post about your app to get some feedback from users. Do a Google search and you will also find other forums that deal with Google TV and will help to get the word out about your app.

The best marketing tool is to have a web site for you app and provide a blog to tell users about updates and plans you have for the app. You should also create a YouTube video to show your app in action. Create pages on the various social networks so that users can follow your progress.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing, **featured apps** are either apps for GTV that are very successful or apps that Google has picked. Currently there is no way of doing anything against that. But I guess Google will work on that if they will continue GTV.